# Finite element analysis in Sage

Tags: sage, finite-element-analysis

Can one do finite element analysis in [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org)? If so, is it static or dynamic?

If not, can somebody suggest an alternative application? I've tried Impact, but it doesn't meet my needs. Matlab is an option but I'd rather not have to buy a license.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe that sage itself has any finite element codes, but femhub (femhub.org) is a subset of sage specifically designed for finite element analysis.